# Which notation/abbreviation is appropriate to denote logical implication while writing proofs/solutions?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, notation

Find $x$ by solving the equation
$$\frac{d (x^{2})}{dx} = 2$$

How should I write the remaining steps of the solution?

Should it be

$\implies 2x = 2$

$\implies x= 1$

**OR**

i.e. $2x=2$

i.e. $x=1$

**OR**

or $2x=2$

or $x=1$

**OR**

$\therefore 2x=2$

$\therefore x=1$

Which notations are appropriate?

Comment: Your first one would be most normal in my opinion. The second one I have never seen. And the $\therefore$ is generally used for a "final important conclusion." I think it's technically correct for the third one,  but very non-traditional.

Comment: Isn't the result $x=2$?

Comment: @PavanC. Okay, thanks.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy How come? Read again.

Comment: You can leave out the symbols altogether —thus reducing visual clutter and improving readability— by simply writing (something like) "We can get to the answer via the following steps:". If individual steps might need later commentary or clarification, be sure to mark them with equation numbers (`\tag{#}` in TeX or MathJax). ... Of the given options, the first is best. (I tend to use "$\to$" instead of the heavier "$\implies$", and I'd add extra whitespace between symbol and equation.) The second and third are too much of a mix of words and symbols; the fourth is an overuse of "therefore".

Comment: It's worth noting the adage *"Know your audience"*. Writing every step is important to guide unfamiliar readers (eg, students) through manipulations, or to highlight a particularly clever trick; it's also important if there may be a mistake that needs to be detected. But, if your audience knows Calculus, then walking through basic algebraic steps wastes their time; just write "and so $x=1$". If there's a bit of work involved: "one can show that $x=1$". Indeed, authors often skip-over even non-trivial arguments with the somewhat cliché "showing this is left as an exercise to the reader". :)

Comment: @Blue Sure, Thanks.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy The result of $2x=2$ is $x=1\,.$

Comment: If..., then... is good enough. Also from..., it follows that...

Comment: Pace @PavanC., $\therefore$ is traditional regardless of the importance of the step. I find $ \implies$ annoying as it reads like a logical connective. The advice to "know your audience" given in another comment is very wise. For most audiences, I'd recommend using words.